How to build C++ project with Apple Hardened Runtime enabled using conan and cmake?
I need to build my C++ project with the Apple Hardened Runtime enabled.
How to do that?
My current build steps are currently:
conan install . --build=missing
cmake --preset conan-release
cmake --build --preset conan-release


This question is being responded already in the Github tracker: https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues/16300

add to your Cmake config:
set_property(TARGET targetname PROPERTY XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_ENABLE_HARDENED_RUNTIME YES)

then:
conan install . --build=missing -c tools.cmake.cmaketoolchain:generator=Xcode
cmake --preset conan-default -G Xcode
cmake --build --preset conan-release


There is actually an even simpler solution:
conan install . --build=missing
cmake --preset conan-release
cmake --build --preset conan-release
codesign  --options=runtime -s identity ./mybin

